# Error on Select

Tags: excel, vba

I have found a error that I don't understand. In (A) statements, I have a error code 1004 - "the Select method of the Range Class failed". (B) statement is Ok. No error. Why can't I use Range("J5").Select with Worksheet object in the second time? I have a few statements between Select worksheet 1 and Select worksheet 2, but I don't believe they interfer.

```
Set wbDF = Workbooks.Add
wbDF.Worksheets(1).Range("H4").Select
wbDF.Worksheets(2).Range("J5").Select  '(A)
```

---

```
wbDF.Worksheets(2).Activate            '(B)
Range("J5").Select
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to *Activate* or *Select* the sheet for you to select a *Range* in that sheet.
So your example (A) doesn't work since Worksheet(2) is not the currently selected Sheet.
[Refer to this post on how to avoid using *Select*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).

Comment: I have avoided using select. Instead, I have used the command directly like in (A), for example: wbDF.Worksheets(2).Range("A8").value = 100.50 - so I hoped that the select command worked the same way. As we have seen, it works only like you said.